# Compute a epsilon normal set

Tags: convex-analysis, variational-analysis

Could you please help to me to compute the following $\epsilon$-normal set:
Given $\epsilon>0$, how to compute the $\epsilon$-normal set of $C:=[2,\infty)\times \Bbb{R}$ at the point $(2,0)$.
Thank you in advanced!
An $\epsilon$-normal set of a convex set $C \subset \Bbb{R}^n$ at a point $z \in C$, denoted by $N_\epsilon(C,z)$, is the following set $\{u \in \Bbb{R}^n \mid \langle u, x-z \rangle \le \epsilon, \forall x \in C\}$

Comment: What is an "$\epsilon$-normal set"?

Comment: "ϵ-normal set": Let $C\subset \Bbb{R}^n$ be a convex set. The $\epsilon$-normal set of $C$ at $z \in C$ is defined by $\{u \in \Bbb{R}^n \mid \langle u, x-z \rangle \le \epsilon\}$

Comment: Shouldn't it be $| \langle u, x-z \rangle |$?

Comment: It seems like I was wrong. According to https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/56171/epsilon-normals-to-convex-sets it seems like one should not take the absolute value.

Answer (score 0):

First find convex normal cone to $C$, at point $z=(2,0)$ which is

$$N(z;C)=  \{u \in \Bbb{R}^n \mid \langle u, x-z \rangle \le 0, \forall x \in C\} =  (- \infty, 0 ] \times \{0\}  $$

Now observe that in finite dimension we have

$$  N_{\epsilon} (z ; C) = N(z;C) + \epsilon \Bbb B $$

Where $\Bbb B$ is closed Unit ball in $\Bbb{R^2}.$

$$  N_{\epsilon} (z ; C) =  (- \infty, 0 ] \times [ - \epsilon , + \epsilon]  \bigcup   \epsilon \Bbb B  $$

Comment: Thank you so much. But if possibe, please clarify the equality $N_\epsilon(z;C)=N(z;C)+\epsilon B$.

Comment: @Dong that's true for convex sets in finite dimension . You can prove it  using separation theorem.


See     https://math.stackexchange.com/q/56171/219176